# PHP Code In PHP Echo

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a Wordpress site using Advanced Custom Fields and need to insert the shortcode value they enter in a PHP template file. I need to insert this code

```
<?php the_field('image_gallery'); ?>
```

into this PHP echo

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('CODE IN HERE'); ?>
```

So that it can output the shortcode the user enters in the PHP template.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this would be to use [`get_field()`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) to `return` the value stored in `image_gallery` to the `do_shortcode()` function:

```
<?php 
    $image_gallery_shortcode = get_field('image_gallery');
    echo do_shortcode( $image_gallery_shortcode ); 
?>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for that. But on the front where the gallery should go it ouputs:

[RoyalSlider Error] Incorrect RoyalSlider ID or problem with query.

Even though the shortcode is correct and everything.

Comment: @user3273481 if the shortcode is correct and the question is answered you should accept it and ask a new question where you can explain your issue a bit clearer, as a minimum you should confirm what the id being requested is and if it exists and the code involved.